# Where do I put the "Allow Access to MyNewCoolApp?" screen in OAuth

Tags: php, oauth

i'm trying to get an OAuth server working but i'm kinda stuck a bit here because i've got it to get a "request token" but I don't know where I put this screen in.

I'm using the library for PHP from http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/php/

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more? You are trying to create an OAuth server, or trying to connect to an OAuth server? The code above is for an OAuth client, not a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out where I put it!
I have to put it on the authorise_token page. [Thanks to this blog post](http://ungeekdapo.wordpress.com/2008/04/04/oauth-explained/)